# Wrapping numbers in a text with span tag with Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to turn this:

```
<p>this is sample 52 for demonstration</p>
```

To

```
<p>this is sample <span class="foo">52</span> for demonstration</p>
```

Via JS / Jquery

52 is just an example, there is long string with different numbers, I want to detect them all
I think its about using regular experession

Sorry Im asking on mobile, dont have editor

Comment: What have you attempted and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Im not sure how to detect the numbers on the string

Comment: I think first I should detect numbers then find the position where numbers start, then make an innerHTML with string + span.foo + string

Comment: But Im sure there must be an easier way or better function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $element = jQuery('p');
var modifiedText = $element.text().replace('52', '<span class="foo" >52</span>');
$element.text(modifiedText);
```

The code will replace all the 52 numbers in all `p` tags with `<span class="foo" >52</span>`. You could adjust it to make more specific.

**UPDATE:**

To wrap all the numbers:

```
var $element = jQuery('p');
var modifiedText = $element.text().replace(/\d+/g, '<span class="foo">$&</span>');
$element.text(modifiedText);
```

**UPDATE 2:**

As @Kamal has mentioned in the comments it would be nice to check if a number was already wrapped. Here is more secure implementation, but it's not necessary:

```
var wrapper = ['<span class="foo" >', '</span>']
var re = new RegExp('(' + wrapper[0] + ')?(\\d+)(' + wrapper[1] + ')?', 'g');
var $element = jQuery('p');

$element.text().replace(re, function(match, p1, p2, p3) {
    if (typeof p1 === 'undefined') {
        p1 = '';
    }
    if (typeof p3 === 'undefined') {
        p3 = '';
    }
    if (p1 != wrapper[0] && p3 != wrapper[1]) {
        return p1 + wrapper[0] + p2 + wrapper[1] + p3;
    } else {
        return match;
    }
});
```

This script doesn't wrap a number if it already looks like this `<span class="foo" >52</span>`

Comment: I dont need to replace 52, there is a long string with has different numbers, I want to detect numbers and wrap them with span

Comment: You can also add regex to find number rather than hardcoding 52..Should be something like :

var modifiedText = $element.html().replace($element.html().match(/\d+/), '<span class="foo" >$element.html().match(/\d+/)</span>');

Comment: @CameronA adding regex as shown in my comment will add the magic for you!

Comment: you may also end up iterating all p tags and adding this logic.

Comment: @CameronA I adjusted my answer. And I'd suggest to add this requirement to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the real use case, here's a simple string replace that will accomplish what you're asking.

```js
document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = document.querySelector('p').innerHTML.replace('52', '<span class="foo">52</span>');
```

```css
span {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>this is sample 52 for demonstration</p>
```

Comment: You can also add regex to find number rather than hardcoding 52..Should be something like : var modifiedText = $element.text().replace($element.html().match(/\d+/), '<span class="foo" >52</span>');

Comment: You logic will only look for 52.. whereas his question is asking for all <p> tags having numbers turning them into <span>